# setting background image behind link tags

Tags: html, css, image

I currently have:
[image]

and I am looking to set the background of the div with links to an image.  Also I only want opacity to apply to the image only, not the links.
This is what I have:

```
#homelinks
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 80px;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 75px;
}

#homeimage
{
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-image:url("http://www.imagegoeshere.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 100% 100%;            
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>
    My Surfing Shop
</h1>
<div id="homeimage">
    <div id="homelinks">
        <a href="http://www.111.html">Home</a> 
        <a href="http://www.222.html">Products</a>
        <a href="http://www.333.html">Surf Reports</a> 
        <a href="http://www.444.html">Surf lessons</a>
        <a href="http://www.555.html">Message Board</a> 
        <a href="http://www.666.html">Directions</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.homeimage` -> `#homeimage` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the CSS for your homeimage div. You have it in your CSS as a class (.) instead of an ID (#). Also the link to your image was invalid (on purpose for some reason I'm guessing). And check the background-position which might need to be 0 0. I'd also remove the fixed background-attachment rule.

```
#homeimage
{
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-image:url("http://www.imagegoeshere.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 100%;           
}​
```

Comment: the class/ID issue was just a copy/paste error, removing the fixed background-attachment and setting the background-position to 0 0 does enable me to see the image now but it is not re-sized to fit the div and the links still have the opacity apply to them as well.

Comment: What browser isn't the opacity working in? You may need to use vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your CSS refers to the class homeimage and **NOT** the ID (that's what it is in your markup).

```
#homeimage
{
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-image:url("http://www.imagegoeshere.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 100% 100%;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use #homeimage in the CSS, the period refers to a class of homeimage.